# How to get contents of va_list in Python?

Tags: python, list, variables, arguments, variadic-functions

(I'm on Windows.)

I have a callback function in Python that is called from a DLL (I use the [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) module). One parameter has the type [`va_list`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/va_list/). Is there a way to get the contents of this? I don't get how to read the correct memory locations ([here](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf)'s a description).

The best would be, if there's a `va_list` parser for Python. Or a DLL that contains functions for getting arguments of a `va_list`.

Does anyone know of a solution?

### I have found a solution:

You can use ctypes to call standard C functions like vsprintf which accepts a va_list parameter. (Formatted printing is want I intended to do).

This is my code to call it:

```
bufferString = ctypes.create_string_buffer(4096)
ctypes.cdll.msvcrt.vsprintf(bufferString, fmt.raw, ctypes.cast(ap, ctypes.c_void_p))
print ctypes.cast(bufferString, ctypes.c_char_p)
```

`fmt.raw` points to the format string, `ap` is the address of the `va_list`.

Comment: Could you submit your solution as an answer (and accept it if appropriate), rather than editing the question?

Comment: Wouldn't this only work for Windows?